# Animate TransformScale of multiple elements by code: c#

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have a bunch of Grid elements like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LevelSegment6" Opacity="1" Canvas.Left="224" Canvas.Top="109" Width="19" Height="33" Background="{DynamicResource SpiritLevelSegment}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
     <Grid.RenderTransform>
          <TransformGroup>
               <ScaleTransform CenterX="-1" CenterY="0" ScaleX="0" ScaleY="0"/>
               <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
          </TransformGroup>
     </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

This is one of 24 Grid elements. All of them have different Canvas positions und angles. The ScaleX and ScaleY values however have to be animated.

To test everything I wrote and tested a Storyboard, like this:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="storyboard">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LevelSegment6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleX" To="0.3" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LevelSegment6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleY" To="0.6" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
</Storyboard>
```

When I start the storyboard the element gets animated as expected but only the one element that is defined in the storyboard. To animate everything I want to create this storyboard per code and run 24 storyboards like this for all 24 grids  at the same time.

This is the code to generate and run those storyboards:

```
   DoubleAnimation animx = new DoubleAnimation();
   animx.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
   animx.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
   animx.To = 0.5;
   DoubleAnimation animy = new DoubleAnimation();
   animy.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
   animy.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
   animy.To = 0.5;

   Storyboard.SetTargetName(animx, "LevelSegment" + i.ToString());
   Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animx, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleX"));
   Storyboard.SetTargetName(animy, "LevelSegment" + i.ToString());
   Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animy, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleY"));

   Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
   storyboard.Children.Add(animx);
   storyboard.Children.Add(animy);

   storyboard.Begin(this, true);
```

All of this is obviously inside a for loop so I can go through all the grids. When I try to run this it throws me an error at "storyboard.Begin(this, true);"

"System.InvalidOperationException" and the description says the object doesn't support this property "RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleX". But it should support this since it is basically 100% the same method I used before in my manually written storyboard. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: As a note, it would be much simpler to assign an `x:Name` to the ScaleTransform e.g. `x:Name="scale1"`, then call `scale1.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, animx)`. You may even reuse a single DoubleAnimation.

Comment: You're right that would be the easiest fix. I always like to keep it as flexible as possible by referencing the top level elements but in this case I only need to animate the scale and nothing else, so this does work. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by placing the "x:Name" into the ScaleTransform instead of the grid:

```
<Grid Opacity="1" Canvas.Left="224" Canvas.Top="109" Width="19" Height="33" Background="{DynamicResource SpiritLevelSegment}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
      <Grid.RenderTransform>
           <TransformGroup>
               <ScaleTransform x:Name="LevelSegment6" CenterX="-1" CenterY="0" ScaleX="0" ScaleY="0"/>
               <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
           </TransformGroup>
      </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

By doing this I can also animate the property directly without using a storyboard at all:

```
DoubleAnimation animx = new DoubleAnimation();
animx.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
animx.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
animx.To = 0.3;
DoubleAnimation animy = new DoubleAnimation();
animy.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
animy.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
animy.To = 0.6;

ScaleTransform scale = (ScaleTransform)FindName("LevelSegment" + i.ToString());
scale.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, animx);
scale.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, animy);
```